# Spring 3 @ImportResouce location from System properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-3

Is it possible to use the @ImportResource annotation with a system property specifying the file location?

This doesnt work:

```
@ImportResource("${properties.location}")
public class Config {
...
}
```

Where "properties.location" is a system property specifying the location of the file.

Comment: Can you try: `@ImportResource("file://${location}")`? It works for me in: `<context:property-placeholder location="file://${location}"/>` with `-Dlocation=...` JVM option.

Comment: Nope...doesnt work: Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ${location}